# This code I use to disable ''PlayerMovement'' does not work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I entered a simple code:

```
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour { 

    public PlayerMovement movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle");
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
        }
    }  
}
```

For a game I'm trying to make but the code is not working. The code is supposed to set the playermovement script to ''false'' when the player collides with an object. Every obstacle I have is tagged and I made sure not to tag the ground but every time the player touches the ground the playermovement script goes to false and it is not supposed to do that with the ground onlt with obstacles. When the player touches an obstacle though everything works good and the playermovement goes to false. I am trying to make the player stop every time it hits an obstacle. I am using unity's game engine.

Comment: Perhaps you could additionally add `Debug.Log(collisionInfo.collider.name);` to see if it is really the ground that is hit and not another object.

Comment: Well did you check if the ground has the "Obstacle" tag?